# Hiding radio input doesn't work

Tags: css, html

This is my HTML code. I want to hide the radio button using CSS, but when I press `F5` it doesn't work.

```css
#ud_tab input[type=radio]{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="ud_tab">

    <input type="radio" name="ud_tabs" id="tab1" checked="">
    <label for="tab1">Headline 1</label>

    <input type="radio" name="ud_tabs" id="tab2">
    <label for="tab2">Headline 2</label>

    <input type="radio" name="ud_tabs" id="tab3">
    <label for="tab3">Headline 3</label>
    
</div>
```

Comment: It does work... What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add double quotes to the attribute selector. Change `input[type=radio]` to `input[type="radio"]`:

```css
#ud_tab input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="ud_tab">

  <input type="radio" name="ud_tabs" id="tab1" checked="">
  <label for="tab1">Headline 1</label>

  <input type="radio" name="ud_tabs" id="tab2">
  <label for="tab2">Headline 2</label>

  <input type="radio" name="ud_tabs" id="tab3">
  <label for="tab3">Headline 3</label>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image: preview]